# Get Union Count Over Multiple Columns -- Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Would like to what excel functions can count the row numbers when at least one column contains certain values? For example, from the below table, if I want to get the row number with at least one column being NULL, the answer should 3

| header | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 'NULL' | 'NULL' | 'NULL' |
| Second | 'NULL' | 'WORD' | 'NULL' |
| Third | 'WORD' | 'NULL' | 'WORD' |

Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated!!

Comment: You may use: `=SUMPRODUCT(--((B2:B4="'NULL'")+(C2:C4="'NULL'")+(D2:D4="'NULL'")>0))`

Answer (score 2):

With Excel365 you do it like-

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A4,(B2:B4="Null")+(C2:C4="Null")+(D2:D4="Null")))
```

[image]

If it is truly null means blank then use-

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A4,(B2:B4="")+(C2:C4="")+(D2:D4="")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add a new column with following function:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"'NULL'")>0,1,0)
```

and then sum all the values in that column